# How to increase the "memory total" that display on Yarn UI?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I have a cluster on EMR (emr-5.20.0) with a m5.2xlarge as Node Master, two m4.large as core and three m4.large as node workers. The sum of memory ram of this cluster is 62GB, but in the YARN UI the total memory displayed is 30GB.

Somebody can help me understand how this value is calculed ?

I have already check the configuration in Yarn-site.xml and spark-default.conf and them is configured according to the AWS recommendadion: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html#emr-hadoop-task-config-m5

Every help is welcome

Comment: As @michal-lemay said you don't include the master node only the worker nodes so you're using the wrong recommended settings.

Answer (score 1):

The memory settings in YARN can be configured using the below parameters of cluster:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

My tweaking these parameters you can increase/decrease the total memory allocated to the cluster.

Comment: But these parameters are configured according to the AWS recommendation. I tried to modified some values, as **yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb** and I restarted the **hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager** but the value of Total Memory didn't change. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Not sure about AWS. I have a cloudera distribution of Hadoop along with Spark2 service. When I change these parameters, the memory related changes are reflected in the resource manager UI of YARN.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn do not include the master node in it's available memory/cores.

So you should get roughly 5 x 8GB (m4.large).  You will get less than that because there are memory overhead left for the OS and services.